# How to close my Launchpad account?

Tags: launchpad

I am surfing the whole [Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net) for a <kbd>Close Account</kbd> option but I can't find it.

The [Privacy Policy page](https://help.launchpad.net/PrivacyPolicy) mention what happens with the data after close the account, but doesn't mention how to do it:

> You can close your Launchpad account and no longer be shown as a
>   Launchpad user. You will no longer receive notifications from
>   Launchpad. However, Launchpad will continue to store and show
>   information about public contributions that you have made.

How can I close my Launchpad account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [login.launchpad.net](https://login.launchpad.net/) then at the bottom is a link which says `Permanently delete account`. Click it (or [here](https://login.launchpad.net/+delete)), and it will be deleted, not deactivated.